# Subtracting Row From Column in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a `m`-dimensional NumPy array `A` and a `n`-dimensional NumPy array `B`
I want to create a `m x n` matrix C such that `C[i, j] = B[j] - A[i]`
Is there a efficient/vectorized way to do this in NumPy?

Currently I am using:

```py
C = np.zeros((M, N))
for i in range(0, M):
    C[i, :] = (B - A[i])
```

**Edit:**
`m, n` are big numbers, thus, `C` is a even bigger matrix (of `m*n` entries)
I tried `np.repeat` and `np.subtract.outer` but both of those crash my RAM

Comment: Have a look at the edit I made to my answer. You can specify the 'out' keyword to avoid any new arrays being created by the operation.

Comment: However you do it you'll end up with an array (M,N) size, and may be two if you do other things with `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ǹp.subtract.outer`

```py
M = 5
N = 10

A = np.arange(N)
B = np.arange(M)
np.subtract.outer(A,B)
```

output:

```
array([[ 0, -1, -2, -3, -4],
       [ 1,  0, -1, -2, -3],
       [ 2,  1,  0, -1, -2],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  0, -1],
       [ 4,  3,  2,  1,  0],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  2,  1],
       [ 6,  5,  4,  3,  2],
       [ 7,  6,  5,  4,  3],
       [ 8,  7,  6,  5,  4],
       [ 9,  8,  7,  6,  5]])
```

It will apply subtraction to all pairs in A and B. For 1 dimension it is equivalent to

```
C = empty(len(A),len(B))
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        C[i,j] = A[i] - B[j]
```

**EDIT**

If you have memory issues you could try allocating the output buffer before doing the operation and setting the `out` keyword appropriately:

```
C = np.zeros((M, N))
np.subtract.outer(B, A, out=C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat one of the arrays on a new axis, and then subtract the other array.

Example:

```py
m = 10
n = 20

A = np.array(range(m))
B = np.array(range(n))
C = np.repeat(B[:, np.newaxis], m, axis=1) - A
```

Then C would contain:

```
array([[ 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9],
       [ 1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8],
       [ 2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6],
       [ 4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4],
       [ 6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3],
       [ 7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2],
       [ 8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1],
       [ 9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0],
       [10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1],
       [11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2],
       [12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3],
       [13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4],
       [14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5],
       [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6],
       [16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7],
       [17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8],
       [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9],
       [19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple broadcasting task:

```
In [31]: A =np.arange(3); B=np.arange(4)
In [32]: C = B - A[:,None]
In [33]: C.shape
Out[33]: (3, 4)
In [34]: C
Out[34]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1]])
```

This is like the https://stackoverflow.com/a/66842410/901925 answer, but there's no need to use `repeat`.  That should cut down the memory usage a bit, but if `M*N*8` is anywhere close to your memory limits, this or subsequent operations using `C` could hit that limit.